# Take record on the same time between two dates

Tags: sql

I have records with datetime column. I need to get the records based on two different dates and same times. I should get records only based on time. i should get records between 9 to 10 (with 10 minutes intervals).

### Time   Count

### 9:00     10

### 9:10   20

### 9:20   05

### 9:30   90

...

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: Wich DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **SQL Server** you could try **DATEPART()** function to filter your results.

REF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174420.aspx

On **MySQL** and **ORACLE** you have **HOUR()**.

REF: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour